# No visible @interface for 'AppDelegate' declares the selector

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, delegates

I'm now writing a registration screen before my tabBar shows up. My idea is to show my registration screen through this method (no dismiss function for now):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.

Register *registerView =  [[Register alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:registerView animated:YES];

return YES;
}
```

Which is in AppDelegate.m 
Unfortunately it doesn't work. Could you help me solve this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`presentModalViewController:animated:` is a method of the `UIViewController` class. Since the app delegate is not a view controller, you can't send it this method. To display your first view controller on screen, assign it to your app's main window's `rootViewController` property:

```
self.window.rootViewController = registerView;
```

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot get it work. Could I ask for the complete code?

Comment: That is the complete code. Obviously, I don't know the name of the variable/property that contains your main window. Just look at any of Apple's project templates. They all include this line.